# I Cannot call any object's methods in Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

Im trying to define this class, and later instantiate it and call some of it's methods.

```
function Layer(){
    this.image = null;
    this.owned = false;
    this.sim = false;
    this.pos = 0.5;
    this.vel = 0;
    this.acc = 0;
    this.lastup = millis();
    this.newpos = 0;

    this.scrub = scrub;
    function scrub(npos){
        this.newpos = npos;
        this.vel = 0;
        this.acc = 0;
    }
}

dummy = new Layer();

dummy.scrub(0.8);
// chrome says Uncaught TypeError: Object #<an Object> has no method 'scrub'
```

Am I defining the methods correctly?

Comment: @Chris - that would *cause* the error.

Comment: Incidentally, this *does* work on FF if I remove the `millis()` call.  This may be an error in the Chrome JS interpreter.  The `function` definition should be hoisted to the top of the `Layer` function's scope.

Comment: Works fine in Chrome for me, as long as I comment out the `this.lastup = millis();` line.

Comment: @Nick sorry, I meant this.scrub = function scrub()...  and by delete i meant remove "scrub;".  hasty typing, my apologies.

Comment: @patrick Well, you obviously have to comment out millis() since you have no such (global) function declared. The OP probably has.

Comment: @Šime Vidas - Yes, my point was that I modified the code from the original. I could have modified it instead to include a `mills()` function. I agree that OP probably has that function, which is why I felt it was OK to comment out since it wouldn't be the source of the issue. :o)

Comment: voting to close. OP states he had an error elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

You're not defining your method correctly. Instead of:

```
this.scrub = scrub;
function scrub(npos){ ... }
```

It should be:

```
this.scrub = function(npos){ ... }
```

<strike>Or you could simply get rid of the `this.scrub = scrub;` line altogether.</strike>

Comment: Thats what I meant in my comment, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Why would it be incorrect? The function declaration is defined first (by the interpreter), then `this.scrub` gets assigned a reference to that declared function.

Comment: @Justin But if he would *just* get rid of the line, then scrub would still be a private function, and therefore not callable as a method. `this.scrub = function() {}` is necessary to make it a callable method.

Comment: This is correct apparently, but my actual problem was that elsewhere in the code, I set dummy = new Object(). :(

Comment: @justin there's nothing wrong with the way it's written. I'd prefer the function definition comes first for organization but it doesn't make a difference here.

Comment: @lincolnk But it the OP wants the function to be a method of the instance then the way to do it is as Justin (and I) wrote. The way it's originally written is just confusing (if nothing else).

Comment: @Šime you might prefer it that way, but the original code is technically fine and none of the answers here are going to fix anything.

Comment: @lincolnk I prefer it? Who wouldn't? Why declare a local function and then assign it as a member, if you can assign it as a member directly?

Comment: @Nathan - This answer isn't correct. Accepting it will just confuse future readers. You'd be better off deleting the question.

Comment: Yeah, I can't delete it though. Sorry to confuse everybody. I voted to close it.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you have to define functions if you want them to be callable "from the outside":

```
this.scrub = function(npos) { ... }
```

Comment: That's effectively what he did.

Comment: no, just as wrong as everyone else.

Comment: @lincolnk It's called a privileged method - http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html

Comment: @Šime the method referenced by `dummy.scrub` and the private `scrub` is privileged. OP is just taking the roundabout way to get there. calling `scrub` out of context of a `Layer` object is going to error, but that's irrelevant here.